# Rebuild a javascript element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a calendar function on our booking system - which currently works (almost) perfectly, however i want to be able to rebuild on request (due to moving from populating data on load to on ajax request). On recalling the function, the calendar fails to rebuild.

//original onload call

```
var calData = <?php echo json_encode($data) ?>;
createCalendar(calData);
```

//new js ajax load

```
 $('#calendar').on("click", function(){
        $.ajax('/event/getCalendarData')
            .done(function(response){
                
                $('#calendar').remove(); //removes el
                $('.calendarInsert').append('<div id="calendar"></div>'); //remake target el
                calData = response; //get data
                createCalendar(calData); //create cal
                
            })
    });
```

//calendar function(not built by us)

```
function createCalendar(calData) {
  !function() {

      var today = moment();
      function Calendar(selector, events) {
        this.el = document.querySelector(selector);
        this.events = events;
        this.current = moment().date(1);
        this.events.forEach(function(ev) {
          ev.date = moment(ev.date);
        });
        this.draw();
        var current = document.querySelector('.today');
        if(current) {
          var self = this;
          window.setTimeout(function() {
            self.openDay(current);
          }, 500);
        }
        
      }
    
      Calendar.prototype.draw = function() {
        //Create Header
        this.drawHeader();
    
        //Draw Month
        this.drawMonth();

      }
    
      Calendar.prototype.drawHeader = function() {
        var self = this;
        if(!this.header) {
          //Create the header elements
          this.header = createElement('div', 'header');
          this.header.className = 'header';
    
          this.title = createElement('h1');

          this.line = createElement('hr')
    
          var right = createElement('div', 'right');
          right.addEventListener('click', function() { self.nextMonth(); });
    
          var left = createElement('div', 'left');
          left.addEventListener('click', function() { self.prevMonth(); });
          

          var append = document.getElementById('calendar');

          //Append the Elements
          this.header.appendChild(this.title); 
          this.header.appendChild(this.line);
          this.header.appendChild(right);
          this.header.appendChild(left);
          this.el.appendChild(this.header);
        }
    
        this.title.innerHTML = this.current.format('MMMM YYYY');
      }
    
      Calendar.prototype.drawMonth = function() {
        var self = this;
        
        
        if(this.month) {
          this.oldMonth = this.month;
          this.oldMonth.className = 'month out ' + (self.next ? 'next' : 'prev');
          this.oldMonth.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
            self.oldMonth.parentNode.removeChild(self.oldMonth);
            self.month = createElement('div', 'month');
            self.backFill();
            self.currentMonth();
            self.fowardFill();
            self.el.appendChild(self.month);
            window.setTimeout(function() {
              self.month.className = 'month in ' + (self.next ? 'next' : 'prev');
            }, 16);
          });
        } else {
            this.month = createElement('div', 'month');
            this.el.appendChild(this.month);
            this.backFill();
            this.currentMonth();
            this.fowardFill();
            this.month.className = 'month new';
        }
      }
    
      Calendar.prototype.backFill = function() {
        var clone = this.current.clone();
        var dayOfWeek = clone.day();
    
        if(!dayOfWeek) { return; }
    
        clone.subtract('days', dayOfWeek+1);
    
        for(var i = dayOfWeek; i > 0 ; i--) {
          this.drawDay(clone.add('days', 1));
        }
      }
    
      Calendar.prototype.fowardFill = function() {
        var clone = this.current.clone().add('months', 1).subtract('days', 1);
        var dayOfWeek = clone.day();
    
        if(dayOfWeek === 6) { return; }
    
        for(var i = dayOfWeek; i < 6 ; i++) {
            this.drawDay(clone.add('days', 1));
        }
      }
    
      Calendar.prototype.currentMonth = function() {
        var clone = this.current.clone();
    
        while(clone.month() === this.current.month()) {
          this.drawDay(clone);
          clone.add('days', 1);
        }
      }
    
      Calendar.prototype.getWeek = function(day) {
        if(!this.week || day.day() === 0) {
          this.week = createElement('div', 'week');
          this.month.appendChild(this.week);
        }
      }
    
      Calendar.prototype.drawDay = function(day) {
        var self = this;
        this.getWeek(day);
    
        //Outer Day
        var outer = createElement('div', this.getDayClass(day));
        outer.addEventListener('click', function() {
          self.openDay(this);
        });
    
        //Day Name
        var name = createElement('div', 'day-name', day.format('ddd'));

       //if(name.outerText == "Sat" || name.outerText == "Sun"){
          //var number = createElement('div', 'day-weekend', day.format('DD'));
       //}
      //  console.log("day-name (innerHTML): "+name.innerHTML);
       if(name.innerHTML != "Sat" && name.innerHTML != "Sun"){

        var number = createElement('div', 'day-number', day.format('DD'));

        //Events
        var events = createElement('div', 'day-events');
        this.drawEvents(day, events);
        outer.appendChild(name);
        outer.appendChild(number);
        outer.appendChild(events);
        this.week.appendChild(outer);
      }
      }
    
      Calendar.prototype.drawEvents = function(day, element) {
        if(day.month() === this.current.month()) {
          var todaysEvents = this.events.reduce(function(memo, ev) {
            if(ev.date.isSame(day, 'day')) {
              memo.push(ev);
            }
            return memo;
          }, []);
    
          todaysEvents.forEach(function(ev) {
            var evSpan = createElement('span', ev.color);
            element.appendChild(evSpan);
          });
        }
      }
    
      Calendar.prototype.getDayClass = function(day) {
        classes = ['day'];
        if(day.month() !== this.current.month()) {
          classes.push('other');
        } else if (today.isSame(day, 'day')) {
          classes.push('today');
        }
        return classes.join(' ');
      }
    
      Calendar.prototype.openDay = function(el) {
        var details, arrow;
        var dayNumber = +el.querySelectorAll('.day-number')[0].innerText || +el.querySelectorAll('.day-number')[0].textContent;
        var day = this.current.clone().date(dayNumber);

        var currentOpened = document.querySelector('.details');
    
        //Check to see if there is an open detais box on the current row
        if(currentOpened && currentOpened.parentNode === el.parentNode) {
          details = currentOpened;
          arrow = document.querySelector('.arrow');
        } else {
          //Close the open events on differnt week row
          //currentOpened && currentOpened.parentNode.removeChild(currentOpened);
          if(currentOpened) {
            currentOpened.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
              currentOpened.parentNode.removeChild(currentOpened);
            });
            currentOpened.addEventListener('oanimationend', function() {
              currentOpened.parentNode.removeChild(currentOpened);
            });
            currentOpened.addEventListener('msAnimationEnd', function() {
              currentOpened.parentNode.removeChild(currentOpened);
            });
            currentOpened.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
              currentOpened.parentNode.removeChild(currentOpened);
            });
            currentOpened.className = 'details out';
          }
    
          //Create the Details Container
          details = createElement('div', 'details in');
    
          //Create the arrow
          var arrow = createElement('div', 'arrow');
    
          //Create the event wrapper
    
          details.appendChild(arrow);
          el.parentNode.appendChild(details);
        }
    
        var todaysEvents = this.events.reduce(function(memo, ev) {
          if(ev.date.isSame(day, 'day')) {
            memo.push(ev);
          }
          return memo;
        }, []);
    
        this.renderEvents(todaysEvents, details);
    
        arrow.style.left = el.offsetLeft - el.parentNode.offsetLeft + 27 + 'px';
      }

      Calendar.prototype.renderEvents = function(events, ele) {
        //Remove any events in the current details element
        var currentWrapper = ele.querySelector('.events');
        var wrapper = createElement('div', 'events in' + (currentWrapper ? ' new' : ''));
    
        events.forEach(function(ev) {
          var div = createElement('div', 'event');
          var square = createElement('div', 'event-category ' + ev.color);
          if(ev.availability == "Full"){
            var span = createElement('span');
            span.innerHTML = ev.eventName+" <br/>Fully booked";
            span.className = "full";
          }
          else{
            var span = createElement('span', '', ev.eventName);
            span.addEventListener('click', function() {
              bookCall(ev);
            });
            square.addEventListener('click', function() {
              bookCall(ev);
            });
          }
          
          
          
          div.appendChild(square);
          div.appendChild(span);
          wrapper.appendChild(div);
        });
    
        if(!events.length) {
          var div = createElement('div', 'event empty');
          var span = createElement('span');
          span.innerHTML = "<br/>Fully booked";
          span.className = "full";
          div.appendChild(span);
          wrapper.appendChild(div);
        }
    
        if(currentWrapper) {
          currentWrapper.className = 'events out';
          currentWrapper.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
            currentWrapper.parentNode.removeChild(currentWrapper);
            ele.appendChild(wrapper);
          });
          currentWrapper.addEventListener('oanimationend', function() {
            currentWrapper.parentNode.removeChild(currentWrapper);
            ele.appendChild(wrapper);
          });
          currentWrapper.addEventListener('msAnimationEnd', function() {
            currentWrapper.parentNode.removeChild(currentWrapper);
            ele.appendChild(wrapper);
          });
          currentWrapper.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
            currentWrapper.parentNode.removeChild(currentWrapper);
            ele.appendChild(wrapper);
          });
        } else {
          ele.appendChild(wrapper);
        }
      }

      function bookCall(ev){
          document.getElementById('call').style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementById('day').innerHTML = ev.day;
          document.getElementById("book").value = ev.event_id;
          document.getElementById('month').innerHTML = ev.month;
          document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = ev.eventName;
          if(ev.availability == "Full"){
            document.getElementById('book').style.visibility = 'hidden';
          }
          else{
            document.getElementById('book').style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
      }
      
      Calendar.prototype.nextMonth = function() {
        this.current.add('months', 1);
        this.next = true;
        this.draw();
      }
    
      Calendar.prototype.prevMonth = function() {
        this.current.subtract('months', 1);
        this.next = false;
        this.draw();
      }
    
      window.Calendar = Calendar;
    
      function createElement(tagName, className, innerText) {
        var ele = document.createElement(tagName);
        if(className) {
          ele.className = className;
        }
        if(innerText) {
          ele.innderText = ele.textContent = innerText;
        }
        return ele;
      }
    }();


    
    !function() {

      var data = [];

      for(var i = 0; i < calData.length; i++){
          data.push(calData[i]);
      }
      
      // console.log(calData);

      var calendar = new Calendar('#calendar', data);
    
    }();
}
```

So as the code exists currently, it gets the data from php on load and createCalendar(calData), when i trigger the click, i get the data again and am attempting to re-run the createCalendar function - however on re-create, i get the following error

```
calendar.js:165 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSame' of undefined
    at calendar.js:165
```

which is the `if(ev.date.isSame(day, 'day')) {` line from `Calendar.prototype.getDayClass`

Can anyone help me figure out how i can rebuild this calendar without refreshing the page

Comment: The problem appears to be that the variable `ev` is created somewhere outside of this function, probably in an event handler which is fired as part of a chain of events.

Comment: OK, thanks, i've had a look at the existing code on this page and it doesn't exist - but there are other scripts being used. I'll rename this ev variable in calendar.js and report back in a few mins if thats working

Comment: It won't work. You should be looking for a function within the existing calendar system that calls `createCalendar()`.

Comment: there are only two places that createCalendar() is called, on the index page on load, and whenever the ajax request is fired. All i want to do is rebuild the calendar with updated data. If i try to call the createCalendar() function with new data being passed, the code breaks because the element still exists

Comment: so is it because the var ev is used in several places within the createCalendar() function?

Comment: My bet without seeing the full code is that ev is an event. An event is a special thing created by an event handler. Say you have an ajax process: the AJAX request has several options of functions to fire based on what kind of response it gets. Those response handlers are called event handlers. The event is a kind of special system data created by a callback function. So you basically need to follow the chain backwards (as you seem to have already done) and create a similar event handling structure, use the system the way it's structured to be used.

Comment: You may be able to "fake" an event by creating your own `ev` object and packing it with the data it expects. But this may require modifying the calendar system's own code. And will almost certainly require using the event handlers as your point of entry for rebuilding the calendar.

Comment: Ah, right - i'm with you. so i've just run the createCalendar() without any ajax, just a request on click to rebuild and it works - the issue is the data in the ajax request

Comment: i'll update my post a bit

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your help. It turns out the data i was getting bk from ajax wasn't json parsed, so it didn't recognise the data